# 'Like' a page using Facebook API or just access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How to 'Like' a page using the Facebook API? or maybe with just the access_token (we can get that with the API)?

I know that it is possible to do it, because my friend told me that he is using a Auto Liker to get likes on his page. The autoliker asks for the access_token and does the task with the help of it. This just means that a page can be 'Liked' with just the access_token.

As far as I know to like a object we need to fire this

```
POST: /$objectid/likes?access_token=XXXXXX
```

But this does not work in the case of pages. How to achieve this?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API method to like a page.

'Auto Likers' use a security exploit to hijack an access token and perform likes on behalf of a user.

This is NOT done using the API, is very much forbidden by Facebook policy, and could also be illegal.

Comment: Correct. You can not like a page using any of the graph api methods. You can use og.likes but you need to be added to the facebook whitelist and submit your open graph action via the app panel to facebook to be approved.

Answer (score 0):

Its not legal to do this according to [Facebook TOS](https://www.facebook.com/policies/).

You can't do this with Facebook API.